# Google Chart Dashboard Control Event Handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-visualization

Is it possible to listen for a selection event in a dashboard control? I've had a look in the documentation but I can't find anything for controls, only charts...

What I'm trying to do is to run a data.group function dependent on a category picker selection  and update a table chart with the resultant dataset.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the "statechange" event to trigger actions when the user interacts with the control.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function () {
    var state = control.getState();
    // do something with state
});
```

Comment: Each control has a different state object with different properties based on what the control does.  The CategoryFilter control, documented at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#categoryfilter has a state with a 'selectedValues' property containing  a list of the 0, 1, or more values selected by the control (as selected by the user or programmatically).